# ¿Como configurar botón de maximizar correctamente en Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++

Hasta el momento esto es lo que tengo. Pero el problema que se me ha presentado en mi interfaz gráfica es que NO SE REGRESA AL ESTADO NORMAL, sino que se queda en estado maximizado.

He averiguado sobre la solución de esta problemática que se me presento, pero no encuentro la solución en el lenguaje que yo manejo (C++). Debo aclarar que aun soy novato en el diseño de interfaz gráfica y agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda y/o información.

Esta pequeña sintaxis de código se aclara que cuando se presiona el botón de maximizar, este quedara en pantalla completa, pero cuando se vuelve a presionar el botón de maximizar no regresa a su estado normal.

Si bien por defectos el botón de maximizar en interfaces normales de Visual studio ya vienen programada. Pero yo he creado la interfaz desde cero y por ende también los botones fundamentales de la interfaz (minimizar, maximizar y cerrar).*/

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^   {
    this->WindowState = FormWindowState::Maximized;
}
```

Comment: Esto parece código *managed* para combinar con C#... pero aunque no fuera así, no entiendo la pregunta, intenta reformularla.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es qué motivación tiene emular el comportamiento del botón de maximizar que ya traen consigo todas las ventanas...

Comment: La pregunta que trate de formular es: ¿Como programar un botón de maximizar en la cual con solo un click se pueda maximizar y normalizar la pantalla de la interfaz?

Comment: @eferion hay [estilos de ventana](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) que no incorporan dichos botones, tal vez al usuario le interesa poder maximizar la ventana en estilos sin botones... pero es sólo una conjetura.

Answer (score 0):

```
System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^)
{
  this->WindowState = FormWindowState::Maximized;
}
```

Con esto pones el estado de maximizado *sí o sí*, mientras que lo que pretendes es que el estado se alterne...

```
System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^)
{
  if( WindowState == FormWindowState::Maximized )
    WindowState = FormWindowState::Normal;
  else
    WindowState = FormWindowState::Maximized;
}
```

Puede que tengas que lidiar con el tamaño del formulario en el caso de pasar su estado a `Normal`... si eso pasa tendrás que decidir si guardar las dimensiones del diálogo antes de maximizar o forzar a un tamaño determinado:

```
Size TempSize;

System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^)
{
  if( WindowState == FormWindowState::Maximized )
  {
    WindowState = FormWindowState::Normal;
    Size = TempSize;
  }
  else
  {
    TempSize = Size;
    WindowState = FormWindowState::Maximized;
  }
}
```